# x86 live image on a x64 processor

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu

I have a live image of ubuntu, and I will be using it for programming. It came with a book, and the book mentions that it has to be used on a x86 based-processor. I have an AMD64 processor, so my question is will this difference affect any of my programming if I run the image on VM because I think the book might dive into ASM. I also read that AMD64 is x86-64, so is it okay ?

Comment: All `AMD64` processors are x86 processors.  AMD64 is a 64-bit instruction set of the `x86 Intel Architecture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it'll run.

A proper modern VM *ought* to run assembly language for the architectures in question with no issue.

Your VM software would have an option for running a 32 bit OS anyway.

[In any case, x64 has support for pure x64 and combined 32 and 64 bit operations under long mode, and 16 and 32 bit operations under legacy mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes). Your processor is probably *frighteningly* backward compatible.